# Usage of serial receive block of simulink to read from COM port of PC giving erroneous value any solution?

Tags: simulink, communication

I was trying to use serial receive block of simulink to read data from COM port. The data is received from an mbed board to COM port and from COM port I want to read it using simulink. When I read it, Im getting some values not related to what I send. Some values like 1.38*e^-38 is showing as output of serial receive block when i try to read '10'. Is this any conversion issue?

I have given baud rates correctly in both ends.

Comment: you need to give way more detail if you want an answer, otherwise it'd be shooting in the dark. At least show some code or add a link to your embedded board and details of your Simulink model. Have you tried feeding commands from a terminal tool like RealTerm?

Comment: Check your data types. Looks like your are sending characters but reading floating point values.